# LIKE query returns 0x80040E14

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2016, oledbcommand

We have upgraded from access 2010 x64 redistributable to 2016 x64 distributable.
After installing 2016 redistributable, query is failing with HRESULT = ( 0x80040E14)

Table FRUITS

```
ID    FRUIT_NAME  FRUIT_DESCR
--------------------------------

1      Apple             
2      Banana  
3      Grape

DELETE FROM FRUITS WHERE FRUIT_NAME NOT LIKE '#*%'
```

Query is executed using

```
CCommand<CNoAccessor, CNoRowset> cmdDelete;

cmdDelete.Open(......);
```

NOTE: Query succeeds if table is empty

Same query passes if I have MS Access 2010 x64 redistributable.
Connection string used -  Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

We have identified that query works correctly in Access 2016 x64 only when below are installed:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Command Line Utilities - 11.1.3000.0
>
> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native client - 11.1.3000.0

However for Access 2010 x64, query worked correctly without above installers.

Is there any other alternative to make query work correctly in Access 2016 without SQL server 2012 installers?